No display on XFX AMD Radeon RX 570 8GB
I recently decided to undertake the task of building my own PC. All my other parts work, but the gpu fans spin and then turn off. Nothing appears on my display either. Is it because I do not have any drivers?  I have plugged in the right 8 pin cable. And my asus prime B55OM-A has only one PCIE slot. My gpu also is displaying the blue light which means it works as normal. I have a 650w power supply. I have 2 16gb sticks of Corsair vengeance ddr4. I also am running a amd ryzen 7, and a thermal light phantom spirit 120 se with argb. I forgot to mention my gpu was from ebay, but the seller said they tested it and said it was in working condition. (came new in box too.)

Here is a list of my parts (except gpu)
https://postimg.cc/qzxFH3sd

And my gpu (same listing)

Original Listing


GPU fans spin up and then stop spinning to make the cards as quiet as possible. Only when the card is tasked with something heavy and starts creating heat, the fans will spin again. So your GPU fans spinning up and then stopping is normal behaviour. You will find that if you start playing a game, the fans will start spinning.

I do not have a display when I plug in my moniter.

Perhaps this might be answered at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Perhaps a dumb question (but then again too much of this mistakes have been asked about here): Are you connecting the monitor directly to the graphics card or using the motherboard's outputs? Knowing your CPU doesn't have any iGPU you must connect to the dGPU -and- resetting the motherboard's firmware (UEFI) is in order.
